# PPT - chart data label alignment using PPTX4J

Tags: java, charts, powerpoint, pie-chart, docx4j

I'm using [docx4j - pptx4j](https://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) to update chart values in a PPT.

The values are getting updated , but the problem is the data label alignment is a mess post update.

What could be done to align label to the best possible position??

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Guys any help ??? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring for long time, I found the solution for my problem.

When i unzipped the ppt file and check that particular chart's XML, there was tag like below

```
        <c:layout>
            <c:manualLayout>
                <c:xMode val="edge" />
                <c:yMode val="edge" />
                <c:x val="0.37500645045178749" />
                <c:y val="0.19924874413552776" />
            </c:manualLayout>
        </c:layout>
```

and removing the manual layout solved the issue :)